# Flow Decomposition theorem explanation

Tags: graph-theory, network-flow

I have a question about *Flow Decomposition Theorem*.

In the theorem say that a flow $f$ can be decompose in $k$ flows, $f_1, f_2 ... f_k$, and the cost of the flow $f$ is equal to the sum of the costs of the flows $f_i$.

My concern is not to messing up the cost of a flow with the value of a flow.

So, I want to know if is correct how I write the formula for this property:
$$f = \sum_{i=1}^{k} f_i$$

Comment: in this script https://theory.stanford.edu/~trevisan/cs261/lecture11.pdf they use the notation $\operatorname{cost}(f)$ for the cost of a flow (see page 3)

Comment: @PinkPanther and what I wrote what is suppose to mean, because I found this notation somewhere, and I don't know what wants to say. First, I think that is the cost, but now is confusing. How you can sum some flows to determine another one?

Comment: A flow is a function from the set $E$ of edges to $\Bbb R_{\ge 0}$, so we can consider a natural sum $f_1+f_2$ of flows $f_1$ and $f_2$ by putting $(f_1+f_2)(e)=f_1(e)+f_2(e)$ for each $e\in E$.